# Android Ignore "multiple definitions of" Error GCC Compiler

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, makefile

I am trying to compile some code for Android NDK and I see...

> multiple definition of 'W_InitCache'

And sure enough there are two classes that import the same header and define the same way. However, the weird thing is the existing branch seems to compile fine. Is there a LD_FLAG (Is that even a thing?) or something I can add to the Android.mk file in order to ignore these errors?

Comment: I don't think there's such an option.  The error means you have a bug in the code you're compiling — a serious bug.  Fix the bug.

Comment: Do the two headers employ the #ifndef/#def technique to avoid included a header more than once?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I need answers not commentary :-) But I do like your enthusiasm.

Comment: @Kerry the problem (as far as I can tell) isn't in the header. It is multiple defs in the implementation functions.

Comment: Can you not take the common definitions out and put them into a single file as a work-around and file a bug report?

Comment: That is what I am trying but it would be way easier if there is a flag. I found a page that says it can be done for G++ but I don't know about gcc.

Comment: @Jackie: the fact that the compiler is complaining is almost certainly something that should be fixed, not ignored.

Comment: I understand I believe the old code commented these out and that was what confused me.